# How to remove automatically generated size for image in url of WordPress

Tags: wordpress

```
http://192.1.1.1/max/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Banner2-300x189.jpg
```

In Wordpress automatic give this url with "-300x189" size how to find and where to find ? for fixing that.

Comment: It is the different image sizes defined by width. - there are many different image sizes, so that the browser doesn't need to download a huge image, where it is not needed. - either just use a different size, or define your own.

Comment: can you give me one example?

Comment: Thumbnails for instance. - you also have, `small, medium, large ` etc. and all the ones defined by your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving different size you want.

```
$size = array('700', '600'),
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );
```

Comment: $size = array('700', '600') this size is every time change.